I am getting a buffer error when using a Typescript RPC library in Vite, Vue
I am using a typescript library that does RPC calls for a blockchain. I am trying to use it in my Javascript and Vue project with Vite bundler.
I have tried install polyfills, buffer etc but somehow I still get the error mentioned below.
This is the library : https://github.com/VerusCoin/verusd-rpc-ts-client
vdxf.js:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined
    at node_modules/verus-typescript-primitives/dist/constants/vdxf.js (vdxf.js:11:59)
    at __require (chunk-BUSYA2B4.js?v=8da589e3:3:50)
    at node_modules/verus-typescript-primitives/dist/vdxf/index.js (index.js:20:16)
    at __require (chunk-BUSYA2B4.js?v=8da589e3:3:50)
    at node_modules/verus-typescript-primitives/dist/vdxf/classes/Challenge.js (Challenge.js:4:13)
    at __require (chunk-BUSYA2B4.js?v=8da589e3:3:50)
    at node_modules/verus-typescript-primitives/dist/vdxf/classes/index.js (index.js:4:19)
    at __require (chunk-BUSYA2B4.js?v=8da589e3:3:50)
    at node_modules/verus-typescript-primitives/dist/index.js (index.js:22:14)
    at __require (chunk-BUSYA2B4.js?v=8da589e3:3:50)
node_modules/verus-typescript-primitives/dist/constants/vdxf.js @ vdxf.js:11
__require @ chunk-BUSYA2B4.js?v=8da589e3:3
node_modules/verus-typescript-primitives/dist/vdxf/index.js @ index.js:20
__require @ chunk-BUSYA2B4.js?v=8da589e3:3
node_modules/verus-typescript-primitives/dist/vdxf/classes/Challenge.js @ Challenge.js:4
__require @ chunk-BUSYA2B4.js?v=8da589e3:3
node_modules/verus-typescript-primitives/dist/vdxf/classes/index.js @ index.js:4
__require @ chunk-BUSYA2B4.js?v=8da589e3:3
node_modules/verus-typescript-primitives/dist/index.js @ index.js:22
__require @ chunk-BUSYA2B4.js?v=8da589e3:3
node_modules/verusd-rpc-ts-client/lib/VerusdRpcInterface.js @ VerusdRpcInterface.js:16
__require @ chunk-BUSYA2B4.js?v=8da589e3:3
node_modules/verusd-rpc-ts-client/lib/index.js @ index.js:30
__require @ chunk-BUSYA2B4.js?v=8da589e3:3
(anonymous) @ index.js:33
Show 8 more frames
Show less

Usage:
This is a connect.js script
// scripts/verusRpcInit.js
import { VerusdRpcInterface } from 'verusd-rpc-ts-client';

let verusdClient = VerusdRpcInterface("iJhCezBExJHvtyH3fGhNnt2NhU4Ztkf2yq", "http://localhost:5173");


export async function testConnection() {
  try {
    const response = await verusdClient.getBlockCount();
    return response; // or any other response you want to handle
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to connect to the Verus RPC:', error);
    throw error; // Rethrow the error to handle it in the caller
  }
}

This is my App.vue:
    <Home/>
</template>

<script setup>
import { onMounted } from 'vue';
import Home from './components/Home.vue'
import {testConnection} from './scripts/verusRpcInit'

onMounted(async () => {
  try {
    // Call your function, for example:
    const result = await testConnection();
    console.log(result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  }
});
</script>



See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . It's unknown how you use it. "tried install polyfills" - what did you try? It's unknown if the lib is usable outside Node environment. It could be

Have updated my question, No it has been used before in Vue, React ETC

"tried install polyfills" - what did you try?

vite-node-pollyfills I suppose

This depends on how you use it. Your specific problem here is Buffer global. I checked the package and it looks that Buffer is the only node thing it relies on, so it has a chance to work. So make sure the plugin is configured properly for Buffer. If the problem persists, please provide a way to reproduce the problem with your setup

For anyone encountering this problem the following configuration might help.
yarn add or npm install vite-plugin-node-polyfills
Open up the vite-config.js file
// 
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { nodePolyfills } from 'vite-plugin-node-polyfills'

// https://vite.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(),
    nodePolyfills({ include: ['fs', 'stream', 'buffer'] })
  ],
})

The same configuration will work for react or any framework using vite bundler
